# Создание файлов для разделов диска в linux

Tags: linux, fdisk

Использую `fdisk` для создания разделов на диске, однако после сохранения изменений, не создаются файлы типа `sda1`, `sda2` и т.д. В каталоге `dev`.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, возможно ли создать файлы для разделов автоматически или придется создавать каждый файл вручную (с помощью `mknod`  например).

Comment: Если в каталоге /dev нет устройств (не файлов!!!) соответствующих типов, то означает только одно - Вы НЕ создали разделы на HD. Выполните команду *sudo fdisk -l*  и покажаите её выдачу.

Comment: @Sergey, вообще-то это как раз-таки **файлы**, а отнюдь **не** устройства. да, «специальные», да, «интерфейсные», да, «псевдо-» (и ещё как-нибудь), но — файлы. по поводу «означает только одно» — не совсем верно. см. ответ. просто программа linux пока не перечитала оглавление, находящееся обычно в первых блоках устройства.

Comment: Две цитаты от Вас:  1) вообще-то это как раз-таки **файлы** 2) находящееся обычно в первых блоках **устройства**. :-)  На мой вгляд, надо слово "device" переводить как "устройство". А насчёт псведо псевдофайлов, это /sys, /run и т.д. Тем не менее, предлагаю не разводить холивар по поводу личных предпочтений.

Answer (score 2):

Файлы разделов в `/dev/` создаются ядром автоматически при чтении ядром таблицы разделов, в частности при загрузке системы, добавлении нового диска или если ядро об этом специально попросить. Вроде бы `fdisk` уже давно научился отправлять ядру `ioctl` сигнал `BLKRRPART`, извещающий о необходимости перечитать таблицу разделов.

Попросить ядро перечитать таблицу разделов также можно [разными другими утилитами](https://serverfault.com/q/36038), например

```
partprobe /dev/sda
```

Comment: Хотел бы добавить, что файлы в /dev/ начали создаваться ядром относительно недавно. Раньше за это отвечал `udev`, а ещё раньше они перманентно создавались для всех возможных устройств при установке системы, а за изменение их набора отвечал администратор. Фактически, остальные способы до сих пор встречаются.

Comment: @Fat-Zer , а "недавно" - это на сколько давно? Я не очень знаком с историей ядра, но ioctl BLKRRPART был уже 15 лет назад: http://lkml.iu.edu/hypermail/linux/kernel/0310.2/0917.html

Comment: BLKRRPART существует настолько давно, что я бы отнёс его к тому, что было «всегда»... А я говорил про то, кто отвечает собственно за создание файлов устройств.

Comment: В седую древность и на всякого рода embended'е за это отвечал пользователь, а весь /dev хранился как-есть вместе с корнем; потом сделали devfs, но все правила именования устройств были прибиты гвоздями в ядре, и он так и не завоевал абсолютного признания. Где-то с веткой 2.6 всё создание устройств отдали на откуп udev'у в юзерспейс, а вот сейчас «недавно», где-то лет  7—9 назад переизобрели devtmpfs, и создание большинства устройств снова находится в руках ядра... Я не всё это самолично застал, так что могу в чём-то заблуждаться...